# Excel - How can you find the exact match of a table row in a separate table if it exists?

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet with two tables:

[image]

I want to find every "row" in table1 that exists as an exact match in table2 using a formula. For example, you can see I have one row in the "matches" table to the right.

So far, I can check for exact matches on a per row basis(this is an Array formula entered using ctrl+shift+enter):

```
=AND(EXACT(A3:B3,D3:E3))
```

How can I do that for the entire range in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a helper column.  In F3 put this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,D3,B:B,E3)>0,MAX($F$2:F2)+1,"")
```

and copy down.  It will fill all duplicates with an increasing number.

[image]

Then you can use this formula in G3:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(ROW(1:1),$F:$F,0)),"")
```

Copy it over one column and down sufficient for your needs.

[image]

It will populate the list with all duplicates.